# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: (wrong name

Tags: java, packaging

my project is in "\BankPrj" folder
It has

(1).com folder

(2)`Account.java`,`Customer.java`,`TestBanking.java` files

(3) main class is in `TestBanking.java`

this is the error..

[image]

this is my complete project

https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0BzMe2Ya7vhrAem5rcEljc3k1cFE/edit

pls correct the errors.

i executed TestBanking.class from test folder itself.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If then post it.

Comment: @codeMaker He tried and put the link. YOu can go and see there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your package is com.mybank.test

The way you should invoke is that go to Folder BankPrj.

now do 
**java -classpath . com.mybank.test.TestBanking**

This should work now.

Remember, you cannot go into the leaf of the folder to execute your class.  You should always stay at the root (when using the package) and execute with fully qualified package name and the class name to execute it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually i tried java TestBanking command from test folder..

Comment: @code_addict Glad, it worked for you!

Comment: @code_addict upvote and accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: @muruga +1 for OP and You. This could come handy for someone in future.

Comment: Thanks! That was very useful. Good demonstration on how to use classpath. I have been trying this for almost an hour. Such questions are useful for raw beginners.