# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello

Tags: java, classpath

This is my first project with Java. I'm using Ubuntu.

I'm in the folder `/home/anis/jtest/myProject` and I run the Hello.java file with :

```
javac src/org/example/Hello.java
```

Seems that works. I get no error and a Hello.class file in the example directory.

Then from the `myProject` firectory again I run :

```
java -cp src/org/example Hello
```

and I get the error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello (wrong name: org/example/Hello)

My code for Hello.java is :

```
package org.example;

public class  Hello  {
        public static void main(String[] args)  {
            System.out.println("Hello\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: see this example
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994613/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-wrong-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In folder src/:

```
$ javac org/example/Hello.java
$ java org.example.Hello
```

Comment: Thats cool! It works now. But I don't understand why we don't use the classpath variable here.

Comment: This answer would be more useful with some information about why the OP's attempt did not work.

Comment: @user3424647 Why do you think you need to set the class path?

Comment: @JasonC that's how the Oracle's java tutorial starts. First lesson is how to set the classpath. Classpath points to the .class files and/or other resources such as libs etc... Thats if I have understand correct :)

Comment: @user3424647 I'm having trouble finding the specific tutorial you are referring to (the [hello world tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html) I see there don't go into directory structure), but in any case: Imagine that "." (the current directory) is *always* on the class path by default. In addition, everything in your `CLASSPATH` environment is there. You don't need to specify the classpath on the command line unless you have class paths that you want to add to that. And secondly (continued)...

Comment: @user3424647 ... your package names are *directly* tied to your directory structure. Since your package is `org.example`, you must either run it from `src/` as `java org.example.Hello`, *or* you *could* use the classpath like this (which might be what you were getting at): `java -cp src/ org.example.Hello`. Your `java -cp src/org/example Hello` was looking for `Hello` in a default unnamed package.

Comment: I'm referring at this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html and Ivor Horton's "Begginig Java 2 - JDK 5" book I have next to me. After installing Java,set JAVA_HOME and classpath are the next steps.

Comment: @JasonC your explanation is great. I have been through so many blog posts but now I think classpath is clear to me. Thank you!