# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError launch error

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I have the typical error in Java. I have the next structure:

```
bin/
lib/
src/
   junior/
         databases/
                  homework/Main.java
```

My **Main.java** code is:

```
package junior.databases.homework;

import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
    private static Connection connection = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        initDatabase();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    private static void initDatabase() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.136.129:5432/postgres", "postgres", "xxxx");
    }
}
```

When I launch it like this:

```
root@debian:/python_codes/Junior/Level1/DB1/ORM/java/java/src/junior/databases/homework# javac Main.java
root@debian:/python_codes/Junior/Level1/DB1/ORM/java/java/src/junior/databases/homework#java Main
```

I got error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main (wrong name: junior/databases/homework/Main)
```

I found in this post the solution **[Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431904/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-hello)**

And my try:

```
root@debian:/python_codes/Junior/Level1/DB1/ORM/java/java/src# javac junior/databases/homework/Main.java
root@debian:/python_codes/Junior/Level1/DB1/ORM/java/java/src# java junior.databases.homework.Main
```

works perfectly.
The problem is I can launch this code only from src/ folder((( Is there any way I can launch it from **/src/junior/databases/homework** folder? I need to go back to src each time I want to launch the code.

Comment: You have to run your command from the root dir /python_codes/Junior/Level1/DB1/ORM/java/java/src/# java junior.databases.homework.Main

Comment: My question is how to run Main.java from homework folder. It is working from src/ folder. Did not understand why i need to go to root dir(((

Comment: It won't work from homework folder. Your Main java class is inside a package : junior.databases.homework , so there is no Main class but a junior.databases.homework.Main class.

Comment: Pity(( Thanks. In this case consider my question unswered.

Comment: @ovod have you had an opportunity to check my answer?

Comment: Sure it works) Now I have to work from src folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are, assuming you are in `src/junior/databases/homework` directory:

```
javac ../../../junior/databases/homework/Main.java
java -cp ../../../ junior.databases.homework.Main
```